# oembed service similar to oohembed (YouTube with JSONP)

Tags: javascript, jquery, oembed

What oembed provider would you recommend instead of the former oohembed? I’m writing a jQuery UI plugin that used oohembed to embed youtube and vimeo since YouTube doesn't support JSONP.

Now I don’t know what to do to embed YouTube – there is no problem with Vimeo. I don’t want to pay for embed.ly because I want to make my widget public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

youtube does support jsonp, try this url: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?v=2&alt=json&callback=foo

And, to embed a youtube video, you simply have an iframe with this as the source: http://www.youtube.com/embed/youtubeid

**Edit(based on comments)**

To get the title of the first entry in the link i posted above, you would use this:

```
success: function(json) {
    alert(json.feed.entry[0].title.$t);
}
```

Comment: What I’m interested in is mainly title, width and height. Youtube oembed has this advantage that I can send maxwidth and maxheight but I can’t see it is possible with its gdata. What do you think?

Comment: The title should be easy to get, however i'm not sure about the width and height. I've never sized a video based on it's height, i always use my own set height.

Comment: One more question. http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/articles/view_youtube_jsonc_responses.html → I can’t see it is possible to query a single video via video id.

Comment: yes, like this: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=YOUTUBEIDHERE&alt=json

Comment: Thank you very much. Though it is not as convenient as oembed I have not choice.